# Protect Excel File upload in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, owasp

I'm trying to implement [OWASP - Protect FileUpload Against Malicious File](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Protect_FileUpload_Against_Malicious_File#Case_n.C2.B01:_Word_.2F_Excel_.2F_Powerpoint) for Excel files in C#.

I'm struggling to find any documentation on how to get every Macro / Vba / OLE_Object.

Here is my current code :

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Utils.FileSecurity
{
    public static class ExcelDocumentDetector
    {
        public static bool IsSafe(byte[] fileBytes)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(new MemoryStream(fileBytes), true))
                {
                    if (document.DocumentType == SpreadsheetDocumentType.MacroEnabledWorkbook
                        || document.DocumentType == SpreadsheetDocumentType.MacroEnabledTemplate)
                        return false;

                    foreach (var sheet in document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        // ???
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you guys have any tips/documentation on this ?
Thanks

Comment: Is it an XLSX file?  I don't think that XLSX files are allowed to have those components.  Yes, of course, a malicious actor can stuff whatever he/she wants in the file.  But, when that file is opened in Excel, it will complain and reject those components.  Take a look at the accepted answer for: https://superuser.com/questions/642419/how-can-you-find-out-if-xlsx-and-docx-files-are-safe-to-open

Comment: `xlsx` files can't contain macros. They are ZIP packages containing XML files with a well defined and known format.. Spreadsheets with macros use the `xlsm` extension. The macros are stored in their own well-defined files. `xls` files are obsolete - abandoned back in 2006 when the new `xlsx` format came out. You can simply refuse to upload files without the `xlsx` extension. If you want to ensure an `xlsx` file doesn't contain macros, you can simply check for the existence of macro files.

Answer (score -1):

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadExcel( HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
        {


           string filePath = string.Empty;
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                string conString = string.Empty;
                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                }

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

                using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                            //Get the name of First Sheet.
                            connExcel.Open();
                            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            connExcel.Close();

                            //Read Data from First Sheet.
                            connExcel.Open();
                            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                            odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                            odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                            connExcel.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }




                string output="";
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    output = output + dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString();
                    output += (i < dt.Rows.Count) ? "," : string.Empty;
                }

                output = output.Remove(output.Length - 1);

            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: public FileResult DownloadExcel()
        {
            return new FilePathResult(Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles/UploadExcel.xlsx"), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UploadExcel()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: @{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "UploadExcel";
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pull-right">

        @Html.ActionLink("Download Sample File","DownloadExcel", "SalaryAdvantage",null)
    </div>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadExcel", "SalaryAdvantage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
        <input type="file" name="postedFile"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Import"/>
    }

    

    
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53259575/edit) to add more to your answer.